# Lebesgue theorem over jordan measurable sets

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove that $f$ is integrable over a jordan measurable set $A$ iff the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure zero, where $f:A\subset \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is a bounded function using the lebesgue theorem:

Theorem: Let $f:R\subset \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ where $R$ is a rectangle. $f$ is integrable on $R$ iff the set of discontinuituies of $f$ has measure zero

I also have the following definition:

$f$ is integrable over a jordan measurable set $A$ iff $f_A$ is integrable over some rectangle $R$ such that $A\subseteq R$

My attempt:

$\Leftarrow$)Let $D_{f,A}$ be the set of discontinuities of $f$ over $A$, $D_{f_A,R}$ the set of discontinuities of $f_A$ (where $f_A=f(x)$, if $x\in A$ and $f(x)=0$, if $x\notin A$) over some rectangle $R$ such that $A\subseteq R$; I know that $D_{f_A,R}\subseteq \partial A\cup D_{f,A}$ where $\partial A$ is the boundary of $A$.

Then I have that $\partial A$ is jordan measurable with jordan measure zero  (becuase by hypothesis $A$ is jordan measurable) hence $\partial A$ has measure zero;  also $D_{f,A}$ has measure zero, therefore $\partial A\cup D_{f,A}$ has measure zero and this implies that $D_{f_A,R}$ has measure zero;

By Lebesgue theorem I have that $f_A$ is integrable on R and by definition $f$ is integrable on $A$

$\Rightarrow$)If $f$ is integrable over a jordan measurable set $A$ by definition $f_A$ is integrable over some rectangle $R$ such that $A\subseteq R$ iff $D_{f_A,R}$ has measure zero(by Lebesgue theorem)

But I don´t know how to prove that $D_{f,A}$ has measure zero from here.

I would really appreciate if you cand lend me a hand

Comment: Note that $\,D_{f_A,R}=D_{f,A} \cup \partial A$.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo can you give me a hint to prove $D_{f,A}\cup \partial (A)\subseteq D_{f_A,R}$: I have that if $x\in D_{f,A}$ this implies that $x\in D_{f_A,R}$ but if $x\in \partial(A)$ how can I guarantee that it´s in $D_{f_A,R}$?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. See [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=34Ic0K3LQxEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=moskowitz+several&hl=it&sa=X&ei=2hcgVZ3rPI22aY65gJgG&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=moskowitz%20several&f=false) the theorem 4.1.42 on p. 250. What do you think of the proof ?

Comment: I don´t think we can guarantee that $D_{f,A}$ has measure zero: we have that: $f$ is integrable on $A$ iff $f_{\chi_A}$ is integrable on some rectangle $R$ such that $A\subset R$ iff $D_{f_A,R}$ has measure zero, and we also know that $\partial(A)$ has measure zero (because it´s jordan measurable) but does that implies that $D_{f,A}$ has measure zero?. In the proof of the link they only did one part of the proof

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately till now I didn't find another _iff_ about the matter.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Read [Zorich's](https://books.google.it/books?id=XF8W9W-eyrgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=zorich+analysis+2&hl=it&sa=X&ei=Fc0gVabzMIPsaJqWgLgP&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=multiple%20integrals&f=false) contribution by Theorem 1 on p. 119.